# Web service that returns localized weather as plain text?

Tags: python, bash, curl, wget, weather

I want to make a very lightweight script to speak the weather. I would need to get the weather status ("cloudy", "thunder"), temperature in °F, wind speed in mph, and humidity in percentage, all based on zip code. I'd like to do this all with curl.

I would want to download the data directly, like "curl http://www.example.com/weather/04101", and have it give me the data in plain text. Would this be a possibility, or would I have to dig around a bit and work on function to get the data?

Comment: Why "no API"? Which service will provide the weather data anyway?

Comment: Well, if you can find a service that provides localised weather information in pain text, then yes.

Comment: @user946850 one that provides plain-text weather data

Comment: "Get a simple string describing weather by post code" === an API.

Comment: @lucase.62: So, you are searching for a web service that will return plain text in the first place. Why the restriction? Are you afraid of other return formats?

Comment: @Hamish: Strictly speaking, yes. But that's not what the OP means, and let's not focus too much on nomenclature here.

Comment: @lucase.62: Why don't you change the title to "Web service that returns localized weather as plain text"?

Comment: @user946850 good idea, I shall do that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/ useful - they have a free (up to 500 uses per day) service, providing local weather forecasts by zipcode or geolocation.

For plain-text, you might also find the NOAA NOW reports useful - http://www.nws.noaa.gov/view/validProds.php?prod=NOW&node=KCLE